# simple congruence with large power and large moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to compute $2^{111455} \pmod{2012}$, but since the numbers are too large, I don't know how to compute it efficiently. I've got: $2012=2^2 \times 503$, $503$ is a prime. And that $111455=2012 \times 55 + 795$ but I don't know if it is useful.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $2^{111455}\pmod {503}$? Because you can probably figure out $2^{111455}\pmod 4$, and then use Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $a^{b+c} \equiv a^b*a^c \equiv (a^b \pmod{n} * a^c \pmod{n})\pmod{n}$ and in particular $a^{2b} \equiv a^b*a^b \pmod{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Using Fermat’s [Little Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Little_Theorem),  $2^{502}\equiv1\pmod {503}$ as $503$ is prime,

and fortunately, $111453\equiv9\pmod{502}$

$$\implies 2^{111453}\equiv2^9\pmod{503}\equiv512\equiv9$$

Multiply by $2^2$ to get $$2^{111453+2}\equiv9\cdot2^2 \pmod{503\cdot2^2}$$

Comment: @goldenz, have you noticed the solution?